# Neo4J Group By Age Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j

I have age field in my **users** Node I need to Group by Age by following groups.

```
'0-9', 
'10-19', 
'20-29', 
'30-39',
'40-49', 
'50-59', 
'60-69', 
'70-79', 
'80-89',
'90-99', 
'100 +'
```

I used following query for that

```
MATCH (n:users)   RETURN count(n.age<25) as group1,count(n.age>25 AND n.age<30) as group2
```

But Get **wrong** count of users. Anyone have idea please share here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `count` function counts the number of occurrences of a variable, regardless of its value:

```
UNWIND [true, false, true, true] as test
RETURN count(test = true)
```

So, you can try something like this:

```
UNWIND [15, 15, 26, 29, 17, 18, 7, 14, 25, 14] as age
RETURN sum(CASE WHEN age<=25 and age>10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as group1,
       sum(CASE WHEN age<=30 and age>25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as group2
```

**Upd**:

As it seems to me, a more simple way to calculate the distribution:

```
UNWIND [15, 15, 26, 29, 17, 18, 0, 14, 25, 14] as age
WITH age,
     REDUCE(acc='', 
              r in [ [0,10,'group1'], [10,20,'group2'], [20,30,'group3'] ] | 
              acc + CASE WHEN age>=r[0] AND age<r[1] THEN r[2] ELSE '' END
     ) as group
     WHERE size(group)>0
RETURN group, count(age)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Save you my lot of time.